# Zurb-Foundation block grid missing cell

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I use Zurb Foundation block-grid layout and experience one issue.
I have this code with Ember.JS

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-5">
         {{render Ember.JS View}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ember produces 7 `<li>` elements which should look like
http://jsfiddle.net/67obcg00/
However, on the page the whole grid is shifted to right. So that the first cell in the first row is empty and the second cell contains `li`#1 of 7.
Eventually, the last row contains two cells instead of one.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kujaqoludi/1/edit?output) in using Ember 1.7 and Zurb 4.1.6

Also a version [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lawahigepa/1/edit?output) using Ember 1.9 beta, Handlebars 2.0 and Zurb 5.4.7

The issue you face using the css selector `[:nth-child][3]` and pre ember.js 1.8 is the meta-morph tags that ember uses know which parts of the DOM it's responsible to update. The nth-child selector will apply the style to the script tags as well as the list element.

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-5">
    <script id="metamorph-10-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
   <li><img src="http://placehold.it/395x590" data-bindattr-287="287"></li>
   <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</ul>
```

Using the css selector [:nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) will only apply to the styles to the type specified.

Cheers I hope that helps.

Comment: I checked my Ember version, it is 1.4.0.
As far as I understood, I should update to 1.8.0 to solve the issue, right?

Comment: Sure Update Ember to 1.8 or write your own block grid. With nth-child. `.small-block-grid-2 > li {
    width: 50%;
    list-style: none; }
    .small-block-grid-2 > li:nth-child(1n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-2 > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: both; }
`